# ZF2 authentication without password

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2, saml

I want to authenticate an user without using a password. So *isValid()* should be set true somehow without using *setIdentityValue(username)*, *setCredentialValue(password)* and *authenticate()*.

How can I successfully authenticate without username/password?

It sounds strange, but in this case the webserver does handle the authentication (SAML). Every user which will granted access by the webserver should automatically get access to the website. I need the ZF authentication because it is also possible to access the website with an username/password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pradeep almost gave the answer. The **Result** should be an array as in the example below.

```
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Result;

class NoPasswordAuthAdapter implements AdapterInterface
{
  protected $identity;

  public function setIdentity($identity)
  {
    $this->identity = $identity;

    return $this;
  }

  public function authenticate()
  {
    return new Result(
      Result::SUCCESS,
      $this->identity,
      array('Authentication successful.')
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own adapter class to do the dummy authenticate.

```
class DummyDBAuthAdapter implements Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface
{
    public function authenticate()
    {
        return Zend\Authentication\Result::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

So, whenever the user is authenticated with SAML you can switch to this adapter from your DB Adapter.

Answer (score 0):

When ZF Authentication came,you have to give some username and password as credentials to the adapter.
which has to be later pass to `authenticate($adapter)` .So as your requirement not to give any credential and set  `isValid() == true`,**you have to do manually by hard coding a certain credential from your DB per every user request**.Here i am giving an example of [ZF2 authentication](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html):

```
    use Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService;

    // instantiate the authentication service
    $auth = new AuthenticationService();

    // Set up the authentication adapter
    $authAdapter = new My\Auth\Adapter($username, $password);

     // Attempt authentication, saving the result
     $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

    if (!$result->isValid()) {
     // Authentication failed; print the reasons why
      foreach ($result->getMessages() as $message) {
        echo "$message\n";
      }
   } else {
    // Authentication succeeded; the identity ($username) is stored
    // in the session
    // $result->getIdentity() === $auth->getIdentity()
    // $result->getIdentity() === $username
   }
```